# Display values of current POST request on page

Tags: php, headers, http

I would like to get some value that was included in the http request header and display it on my webpage, i.e:

- I have a webpage, say: '*mywebsite.com*'
- I have a POST request to '*mywebsite.com*' with a variable (lets call it `var_A`) in its header
- Then I would like to display the value of `var_A` on '*mywebsite.com*', i.e. add it to the HTML

---

I've found things like: `get_the_content()` that will return the  POST content of the current page. I can add that to my website using the *Code Snippets* plugin, however, I can't seem to understand how to then display the content values (like `var_A`) on the webpage itself.

I'm a bit lost on how to connect the PHP stuff to the JavaScript that runs in the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter_var` or, more directly, [`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to retrieve data from the REQUEST data.

```php
$var_a = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'var_a', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

The above code will get `var_a` out of the `$_POST` data, and sanitize according to PHP's `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`. You can read the PHP Manual on [Types of filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) for other data types.

Comment: Amazing! This works perfectly with a custom PHP shortcode, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to hook into `get_query_vars` and do a little customizing there.

From the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/):

> `get_query_var()` only retrieves public query variables that are
> recognized by WP_Query. This means that if you create your own custom
> URLs with their own query variables, `get_query_var()` will not
> retrieve them without some further work (see below).
> Custom Query Vars
>
> In order to be able to add and work with your own custom query vars
> that you append to URLs (eg: `“http://example.com/some_page/?my_var=foo”`
> – for example using `add_query_arg()`) you need to add them to the
> public query variables available to `WP_Query`. These are built up when
> `WP_Query` instantiates, but fortunately are passed through a filter
> `‘query_vars‘` before they are actually used to populate the `$query_vars`
> property of `WP_Query`.
>
> So, to expose your new, custom query variable to WP_Query hook into
> the ‘query_vars‘ filter, add your query variable to the $vars array
> that is passed by the filter, and remember to return the array as the
> output of your filter function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This only handles `$_GET` parameters and has to have a lot of overhead RE hooking into `query_vars`. The best way to do this that I'm aware of is to use `filter_input` or `filter_var`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think I misunderstood what you were after to begin with. Glad to see you worked it out!